# Paypal Payments Pro - Transfer Shopping Cart Line Items?

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, paypal-payments-pro, paypal-pro, transfer

I am using Paypal Payments Pro in Magento 2.3.1. I have Paypal Express checkout enabled as an alternate checkout option.

First of all, let me clarify that both payment options are working just fine - the transactions go through, and the orders are being properly received and created in Magento.

That said, with express checkout there is an option in the configuration to enable "Transfer Cart Line Items". When set to "Yes" this works as expected and the item details (Product name and sku) are transferred to Paypal and show on the Paypal transaction details.

Orders placed with a credit card (through Payments Pro) however, do not show the product details (Product name and Sku) on the Paypal transaction details.

Is there a setting for this? I can't find anything related to it in the configuration settings.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke with PayPal Merchant Technical Support - apparently cart line items are only transferred with the basic Paypal Express Checkout integration. If you are using Paypal Payments Pro it uses the Payflow gateway for both Express and CC transactions and the cart line items do not transfer.

According to them, this is just how it is and they don't plan to improve it - just in case anyone else was wondering.